# Add special prefix to all files in directory

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-rename

I have a directory with a certain number of mp3 files, that are sorted by name, for example:

```
Artist.mp3
Another artist.mp3
Bartist.mp3
Cool.mp3
Day.mp3
```

How can I add a unique continuous 3-digit prefix to each file, but in a random order, so that when sorting by name it would look something like this:

```
001 Cool.mp3
002 Artist.mp3
003 Day.mp3
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File
$global:i = 0; Get-Random $files -Count $files.Count | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {"{0:000} $($_.Name)" -f ++$global:i} -WhatIf
```

Or in the unlikely event the filename contains curly braces :-):

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File
$global:i = 0; Get-Random $files -Count $files.Count | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {("{0:000} " -f ++$global:i) + $_.Name} -WhatIf
```

Or as @PetSerAl suggests, using `[ref]$i` as a good way to avoid global vs script scoping issues altogether:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File
$i = 0; Get-Random $files -Count $files.Count | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {"{0:000} {1}" -f ++([ref]$i).Value, $_.Name} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks good remove the `-WhatIf` and run this again to actually rename the files.

Comment: What if `$_.Name` contains `{` or `}`?

Comment: thanks, just one edit: renamed `$i` to `$global:i` otherwise it would go over 100  when i run the script more times

Comment: Yeah my command was assuming running from the command prompt so the `global` in `$global:i = 0` was not necessary.  In a script I would use `$script:i` in both places that reference/modify the variable.

Comment: @PetSerAl Somewhat of a corner case but OK, updated the answer.  :-)

Comment: @KeithHill Why not `"{0:000} {1}" -f ++$global:i, $_.Name`, and you missing `{`. And for scope problem, I propose `$i=0` at start and `++([ref]$i).Value` for increment, so you does not have to assume running from command prompt or script.

Comment: @PetSerAl Fixed the copy/paste bug (missing { ).  I like the [ref] suggestion.  I'll update the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably go with `$files | Get-Random $files.Count | %{$i=0}{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ... }` to solve the pesky `$i` problem.